# RhoMobile using RhoMobile Beginners Guide

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

Hey guys I am doing the application from the book RhoMobile Beginners Guide but the code samples in chapter 5 page 99 are not working.  If anybody who has already used the book can provide the correct code I will be extremely thankful.

Also I have started learning Rhodes recently so if anyone can provide good links to get started it will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.railshorde.com/blog/rhomobile-rake-commands-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RhoMobile was bought by Motorola so now they took over the documentation:

Here you can find examples as well:

http://docs.rhomobile.com/

if you have any question you can ask us on the forum for developer:

https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/welcome